# Can you be a Reborn Dhampir?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races

Can you combine Reborn with Dhampir? Both are "lineages" that combine with another race and keep certain things such as climbing speed (which dhampirs get), so could you have both or is there a rule I missed? I'm talking RAW, assume the DM won't smite the combo as I'm building for a very powergamey group.

Comment: @RallozarX That sounds like enough information to be a valid answer. Please feel free to post it as one. However since it's so close to an answer I've removed it as a comment.

Answer (score 11):

### No, one per customer

Per the [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/706719-lineages#CreatingYourCharacter) of Creating Your Character:

> At 1st level, you choose whether your character is a member of the human race or of one of the game’s fantastical races. Alternatively, **you can choose *one* of the following lineages**. If you choose a lineage, you might have once been a member of another race, but you aren’t any longer. You now possess only your lineage’s racial traits.